# How can I INSERT or UPDATE values into a DB through code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

I am currently in development of the Administration page for my site. Currently, I am trying to develop User Rolls and Rules.

My DB is structured like this:

---

**tblSiteUserRolls**

```
id
rollName
rollDescription
```

---

**tblSiteRollAccess**

```
id
accessName
accessDescription
```

---

**tblSiteRollLink**

```
id
rollId
rollAccessId
allowed
```

---

**tblSiteMemberDetail**

```
~stuff~
userRollId
```

---

I have manually added the `rolls` and `rollAccess`, and displayed them on a `Repeater` control, with little check boxes next to the name. This all currently works flawlessly.

This works by adding all the `rollAccess` to a generic list, and setting all the values for `allowed` to 0. I then check for all the `rollAccess` to the *selected* `roll` from the **tblSiteRollLink**, and if its there, set the `allowed` to 1.

Is there a quick way to INSERT or UPDATE the records in **tblSiteRollLink** with the edited values other than iterating through all my values in the `repeater` and manually doing it?

Here is some code:
Page.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptRollRules" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Roll Rules
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Access Name
                    </th>
                    <th>Allowed
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRollId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RollId") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAccessId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccessId") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAccessName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccessName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsAllowed" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("AccessAllowed") %>'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Page.cs

```
private void PopulateRollRulesRepeater(string rollId)
    {
        // Get all the access rolls
        List<RollAccess> access = new List<RollAccess>();

        string strSql = "SELECT [id]" +
                              ", [accessName]" +
                              ", [accessDescription]" +
                              " FROM tblSiteRollAccess";

        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };

        SqlDataReader rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            access.Add(new RollAccess
                {
                    RollId = rollId,
                    AccessId = rdr["id"],
                    AccessName = rdr["accessName"],
                    AccessDescription = rdr["accessDescription"],
                    AccessAllowed = false
                });
        }

        rdr.Close();
        DataConn.Disconnect();

        // Check if the current roll has the access
        strSql = "SELECT [rollAccessId]" +
                 ", [allowed]" +
                 " FROM vwGetRollAccess WHERE rollID = @id AND allowed = 1";

        sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strSql, DataConn.Connect()) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = rollId;

        rdr = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            foreach (RollAccess rollAccess in access.Where(rollAccess => rollAccess.AccessId.ToString() == rdr["rollAccessId"].ToString()))
            {
                rollAccess.AccessAllowed = true;
            }
        }

        rdr.Close();
        DataConn.Disconnect();

        rptRollRules.DataSource = access;
        rptRollRules.DataBind();
    }

    public class RollAccess
    {
        public object RollId { get; set; }
        public object AccessId { get; set; }
        public object AccessName { get; set; }
        public object AccessDescription { get; set; }
        public object AccessAllowed { get; set; }
    }

/// <summary>
/// Update the Roll's details and access levels
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable rules = new DataTable();
    DataColumn rollId = new DataColumn("rollId", typeof(int));
    DataColumn rollAccessId = new DataColumn("rollAccessId", typeof(int));
    DataColumn allowed = new DataColumn("allowed", typeof(int));

    rules.Columns.Add(rollId);
    rules.Columns.Add(rollAccessId);
    rules.Columns.Add(allowed);

    DataRow drRules = rules.NewRow();

    // Update the access levels
    foreach (RepeaterItem i in rptRollRules.Items)
    {
        //Retrieve the state of the CheckBox
        CheckBox chkIsAllowed = (CheckBox) i.FindControl("chkIsAllowed");
        Label lblRollId = (Label) i.FindControl("lblRollId");
        Label lblAccessId = (Label) i.FindControl("lblAccessId");

        drRules["rollId"] = lblRollId.Text;
        drRules["rollAccessId"] = lblAccessId.Text;
        drRules["allowed"] = chkIsAllowed.Checked.GetHashCode();
    }

    string strSql = "";
}
```

/Current/ SQL

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Darren Whitfield
-- Create date: 24 April 2013
-- Description: This will update the user roll rules
-- =============================================

CREATE TABLE [rulesTable]
( 
     [ID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     [rollId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [rollAccessId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [allowed] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TYPE [rulesUDT] AS TABLE
( 
     [rollId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [rollAccessId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [allowed] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE procUpdateUserRollRules 
@tbl rulesUDT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [rulesTable] SELECT * FROM @tbl

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you've done your middle-tier, this should be possible.

You'd need to pass the list of values as a table to SQL Server, into a stored procedure that accepts table-type parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

In that stored procedure, you could use the MERGE command, to INSERT/UPDATE in a single operation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb510625.aspx

Here's an example with C# from another question on this site [Passing datatable from C# to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408457/passing-datatable-from-c-sharp-to-sql-server-2008)

OK looking at your code sample for the postback, some pseudo-code:

```
    // Update the access levels
    foreach (RepeaterItem i in rptRollRules.Items)
    {

DataRow drRules = rules.NewRow(); //One table row per repeater row

        //Retrieve the state of the CheckBox
        CheckBox chkIsAllowed = (CheckBox) i.FindControl("chkIsAllowed");
        Label lblRollId = (Label) i.FindControl("lblRollId");
        Label lblAccessId = (Label) i.FindControl("lblAccessId");

        drRules["rollId"] = lblRollId.Text;
        drRules["rollAccessId"] = lblAccessId.Text;
        drRules["allowed"] = chkIsAllowed.Checked.GetHashCode();

rules.Rows.Add(drRules); //Add your row to the data table
    }

cmd = new SqlCommand(); //Can't remember the syntax
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC YourMergeStoredProcedure @YourDataTable";
SqlParameter sqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourDataTable", drRules);
sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Don't forget, you'll need to create the table-type in SQL Server so it knows what to expect. See the links above for how to do that. Also my code is just to give you the idea, I'm writing off the top of my head here so there will be errors.

Comment: It's not as bad as it looks :) Just be careful with big lists, I've had issues with 100k rows in a table-type crashing the server...I don't think you'll hit that with users/roles, but you never know ;)

Comment: I doubt the user rolls will go over 50 :P But good insight IF I ever have to do a mass import.. I've updated my question with code if that helps.

Comment: Well, the code you'd use for the update isn't up there, but that's OK :) In the post-back, you'll take all the checkboxes & roles from the page, and make up a datatable to pass to SQL server as per the above links. Should only be a dozen or so lines of code :)

Comment: Yeah, I decided to post and ask for the right way first before I was happy with bad code :)

Comment: Alright, got the whole `DataTable` working. Unfortunatly this is still new territory, and I'm afraid that past adding the rows, I'm stumped. :/ - Updated the code.

Comment: @NewAmbition I've put some pseudocode up to give you the rough idea, hopefully that'll get you going :)

Comment: thanks! That helps immensley! I'm sorry to keep this going - but as I said, I'm not familiar with this at all... My last concern is with the actual SQL Procedure.. I've posted what I compiled using the examples - but I dont think it will be right at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28804/discussion-between-newambition-and-meff)